# python webkit webview: Why does the history have dates that equal 0.0, and what needs to be fixed?

Tags: python, webkit, history, gtk3

**I'm using GTK3 with python.**

While accessing the backforward list the `get_last_visited_time` returns 0.0

The `get_last_visited_time` is being called in the notify status signal callback on `load_status = FINISHED`.

All the other values like uri, and title are the correct values.

Comment: Is this about GTK WebKit View, wxWidgets, Qt or something else entirely?

Comment: @mfitzp I changed the question body. Also added a tag for gtk3. Probably  why I wasn't getting any answers.

Comment: Ha, might have something to do with it. I'll take a look now.

Comment: I think it might be a WebKit bug, see here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60940  ...although that dates from 2011, and no fix. It could be that the Python WebkitGTK is relying on some missing function. It is http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/ that you're using?

Comment: I'm getting it from gobject so I don't know. I'll try to see if I can find out. I have webkit 3.

Comment: I mean I have gir1.2-webkit-3. That uses webkitgtk+.

Comment: Does the HistoryItem have a get_last_visited_time() method?

Comment: Yes it does. http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitWebHistoryItem.html#webkit-web-history-item-get-last-visited-time and that's the one I'm using.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question so I tested this again to see if it was fixed. Still didn't work. I'm considering submitting a bug report. Unless there's something I've overlooked.

Comment: Sorry Quentin, this dropped off my list. I think submitting a bug is the way to go, the bug I linked to looks like it's the source of the problem, but it's dependent on whether it's fixed in whichever version you have.

Comment: That's fine. The bug link is for qt any way. I might try the gtk/webkit mailing list too.

Comment: Why did this question get a thumbs down?

Comment: No idea. It's a completely valid question, that turned out to be unanswerable because of a bug. I've thumbed it back to zero.

Comment: It looks like webkit2 doesn't even have a time or a function to get the time from the history. I believe the version I'm using is 1. Some of the functions from 2 cross over to one, aren't documented, and some functions that are in 1 are not even in 2. I think it's just a really new library that has developers still trying to work out exactly how they want to implement things. I'll just have to work with what I got. They work hard. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The history recording is supposed to be automatic. In this case, there is either no history command, or the appropriate command has not been initialized. You have to set a command to start the clock at a certain point, or else the time will always be 0 from the clock's point of view. I don't know the actual command, but hopefully you will understand the concept.

Comment: I'm using an analogy to say that a watch that is not started will always display zero. I imply that if Python does not start displaying the history automatically or it is not told to start displaying the history, the history will always show zero. You will say something like:" The current time is time zero, for every time this link is clicked/page visited, add 1 to the increment" If it displays an actual time, it will say, this page visited x hours ago, if you add an instruction to display the time in hours and minutes to the increment.

Comment: There is not a function for that. It's just an ordered list that gets automatically updated. I would think it would use the system clock. I would understand if there was a way to set a callback for a function that gets the system time, but there is no ready way to do that in webkit. Looks like I will have to manually set history items. I didn't want to do that. I can, but why would it be automatic if I had to set them manually to get a history time?